# How to grant privilege for an Oracle trigger to access a function from other schema

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a problem that I try to call functions from a trigger. This function is from a different schema. I granted privileges for the user of the trigger to access the functions:

```
select 'GRANT EXECUTE ON VARTABLE.SEATS TO OWNER_OF_TRIGGER;' from all_objects where owner = 'xxx' and object_type='FUNCTION';
```

However, this does not work. Is this somehow possible or do I need to copy the functions to the schema of the trigger?

```
create or replace TRIGGER CALCULATOR 
AFTER INSERT ON PEOPLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
<<VARTABLE>> DECLARE
SEATS NUMBER;
INCOME NUMBER;
CANNOT_CHANGE_VALUE EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COMPANY.SEAT(5,0.5,3.5) INTO VARTABLE.SEATS FROM DUAL;
    SELECT COMPANY.INCOME(3,360,500) INTO VARTABLE.INCOME FROM DUAL;
    IF INSERTING THEN
      INSERT INTO CALCULATIONS (cd_id,
      SITTING_PLACE,
      INCOME) VALUES (:NEW.CD_ID,
      VARTABLE.SEATS,
      VARTABLE.INCOME);
    END IF;
  END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda calling back to my Oracle days, but you should be able to create a Synonym to handle the link.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. I can post directly into SQL worksheet of the the owner of the trigger:
select SEAT(5,0.5,3.5) from DUAL;
And this works.
However, if I try to do the same from the trigger I got the same insufficient privileges error.